# Google Forms - Script to add repeating question with optional repeating question nested after each response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, infopath

Quick summary - my job is being crappy and expecting an investment admin to create something beyond my capabilities.

My end goal is to have a Google Form (or other accessible option) where someone can type in the name of their child, click a button to add any grandchildren underneath that child, then be able to add additional entries of either children or grandchildren. The output essentially looking like this:

Child name
Grandchild name
Grandchild name
Child name
Child name

Microsoft's InfoPath 2013 allows for this using a repeating section (the repeating control being a text box) and inserting an optional section (which contains a simple repeating list control) into the repeating section. That allows users to add as many children or grandchildren as they need without inserting a giant empty table and each user submitting a different format.

Since pretty much no one has InfoPath Filler and almost none of them use Outlook for personal email, at least one of which is required to fill out a form created in InfoPath, I wanted to use a more accessible option. I landed on Google Forms, but they don't have options to create something similar, and none of the existing add-ons seemed to provide that capability. I would love to be able to write a script to solve this problem, but that is way beyond my capability.

Does anyone here have any suggestions or know how I could solve my problem?

Comment: Hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: @Cooper Unfortunately, being essentially a receptionist, I don't have the latitude at my organization to hire anyone, and I definitely won't spend my own money to do so. Obviously I'm expecting someone on here to do it for me for no recompense, I was just hoping someone could point out something I missed or point me in the right direction.